# Turn on Gzip for combined JS or CSS files without file extension

Tags: nginx, gzip

I'm trying to configure GZip on my nginx server. It works for files with an file-extension.

> To make a decision what kind of file is served over the network, Nginx does not analyze the file contents ... Instead, it just looks up the **file extension** to determine its MIME type

So when I have a combine css file without a file extension it doesn't know it needs to be gzipped and serves it plain.

Is there a way to let nginx know that everything served from a specified location always needs to be gzipped. With or without an file extension?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working:

```
    location /files {
      types         { } 
      default_type  text/css;

      gzip  on;
      gzip_min_length  1;
      gzip_proxied     any;
      gzip_types       text/css;
      gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
      gzip_comp_level  6;
    }
```

And test:

```
curl -v localhost/files/test1
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /files/test1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.3
< Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2016 07:23:17 GMT
< Content-Type: text/css
< Content-Length: 13
< Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Jun 2016 07:23:08 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5768eb5c-d"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
MY DATA HERE
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

File without extension was sent as text/css mime. Or what do you need? text/html?

Now test gzip:

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" localhost/files/test1 | gunzip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    33    0    33    0     0    217      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   218
MY DATA HERE
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a location for these files and set default_type for them...
But why are you doing such a strange thing?

It could be soemthing like this:

```
server {
  server_name my_server.com;
  listen 80;
  location /my_files { 
    types         { } 
    default_type  text/css;
 }   
}
```

Theoretically it should send all files under this location as "text/css" mime type. But I have never did this and have no idea will it work. Gzip could be enabled in the location too.

Anyway, more inromation could help.

Comment: This isn't an answer - you're asking a clarification to the OP, so post a comment under the question.

Comment: "But why are you doing such a strange thing?" I think you mean the combining of files without extension? Well that's part of the CMS which I can't easily alter. Complicating factor is that both JS and CSS files are in the directory. And by default they are already transfered as text/html and should be gzipped by default. But they are not.

Comment: Ok, try to create nginx location for this directory, set the default_type there. Nginx uses types to find out what to gzip too http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html I hope it will work together with the default_type

Comment: Nope. this is not working

Comment: I've managed to make it work.